# Calculating the degree of a map between non-sphere topological spaces.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

**Problem.** Let $X$ be a genus 2 surface made by attaching two one-holed tori along their boundaries. Let $A$ be one such torus. Let $Y$ be a torus and $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be the map obtained by contracting $A$ to a point. Write the long exact sequence of homology associated to the pair $(X,A)$ and calculate all the terms of this sequence. What is the degree of $f$?

I was able to write the L.E.S. for the pair $(X,A)$. However I am failing to see how to calculate the degree of $f$. My understanding is that the notion of degree of a map only works for maps $f:S^n \rightarrow S^n$. Would this therefore be a trick question to see if we know degree isn't defined for tori? I am using Hatcher's textbook and have only read through chapter 2 (homology).

Comment: Degree makes sense for any map between oriented n-manifolds. You just look at the induced map on top homology which is a map $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip thank you!